# Print like Firefox

Tags: printing, wget, firefox, ps, html

Made a CLI script to print Wikipedia articles:

```
WIKI='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title='
TITLE=$1
PRINTABLE='&printable=yes'

SRC=$WIKI$TITLE$PRINTABLE

HTML=$1".html"
PS=$1".ps"

wget $SRC

mv index* $HTML

html2ps $HTML > $PS

lpr -P pr1444 $PS
```

It works in the respect that if you write `./print Shane_Mosley` [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shane_Mosley&printable=yes) is printed.

But, compared to using Firefox --- navigate to the site, and print from the menus --- the printed result is inferior: much less compact layout (especially tables), no pictures, and cannot handle "unusual" characters.

So, my question: Is Firefox "monolithic" or is it actually composed of modular tools, that I can replicate? Or could I use Firefox as a server, that I can feed commands (like go there and print)?

If no: are there ways to use my tools in a better way, or are there other tools that would enhance the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, this method is suboptimal at best. In addition to the HTML you'll need at a minimum all images and CSS. You may also need all of the Javascript. And then there's the whole deal of rendering this mess.

But for you there is good news in the form of a [Command Line Printing](https://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2) extension you can install in Firefox.

Then:

```
firefox -print http://www.example.com/index.html
```

There are more examples on the extension documentation page.

Comment: Wow, that's great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to `grep` the `$HTML` var and find any `<img src=..` element and then replace every `src` attribute with the full image path like `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uncle_Tupelo.jpg`. By defaut, the server pages technology keeps the image source to the servers relative path like in this case `<img src="File:Uncle Tupelo.jpg">`. Most of these values are derived from CSS. This will solve the image problem in your print outs, however other CSS element details might still be missing.

An alternative to `wget` would be to use a quick Perl script.

Comment: Do you mean I should get the picture paths that way, download them individually and perhaps iterate a list to print them as a sort of appendix at the end of the document?

Comment: Yes, that is the most feasible way to get the pictures using `wget` i guess. More importantly if the `<img src=..>` points to a relative path (which is the case with almost all websites) then you have to tell the `<img>` element exactly where the image resides in the server (like `https://www.somesite.com/images/image001.png`) and not just the relative path (like `/images/image001.png`).